# PHP-FPM slowlog and Mysql lost connection

Tags: mysql, php-fpm, percona, packets

I was having an issue with PHP-FPM and mysql. When I needed to process an input file that would generate several selects/inserts/updates for each line, it would stop after approximately 60s with message `Lost connection to the server` or `Mysql server has gone away`. The queries were simple, just update a few fields, no BLOBs, less than 1KB each.

Disabling PHP-FPM for MOD_PHP solved the issue - but it was not a ini setting problem, because they both shared the same ini file.

It turned out to be `request_slowlog_timeout` as suggested by [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/559165/percona-got-an-error-writing-communication-packets/). It doesn't make sense because it isn't supposed to terminate or interfere with the script execution, as I understand

My question is, is it a bug in PHP-FPM or it's just that I'm missing something?

> Server Config:
>
> Percona Mysql 5.5.19, Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips Domain Server mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1, PHP 5.3.24